# `NetNestOperator` with custom input / output ports

Tags: neural-networks, implementation-details

I'd like to use `NetNestOperator` on a `NetGraph` that has custom input / output port names, such as

```
net = NetGraph[<|"y" -> LinearLayer[1]|>, {NetPort["x"] -> "y" -> NetPort["x"]}, "x" -> {1}]
```

This should be doable, since there's a one-to-one mapping between the input and output port names (in this case, they are identical), but Mathematica complains when I try for example `NetNestOperator[net,2]`:

> NetGraph::netinvgport: Input is neither a valid input or output port for the given NetGraph.

Of course, for this simple example using

```
net = NetGraph[<|"y" -> LinearLayer[1]|>, {NetPort["Input"] -> "y" -> NetPort["Output"]}, "Input" -> {1}]
```

works just fine, but

1. There's no way to generalize this to multiple inputs and outputs (*i.e.* using "Input1", "Input2", ... and "Output1", "Output2", ... doesn't work)
2. Custom port names are nice!

Is there maybe an undocumented option specifying the port mappings in `NetNestOperator`?

Answer (score 4):

For the ports name problem, I'm not aware of any ready-to-use way, but I think it is always doable to re-map the ports to "standard" names through a dummy net. For example

```
NetGraph[{net}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> NetPort["Output"]}] // NetNestOperator[#, 2] &
```

For the multi-ports problem, according to [the doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetNestOperator.html#1067943069), I don't think `NetNestOperator` is meant to handle that. But it's easy to make one with WL's functional programming capability. For example using `FoldPairList`:

```
mutiportNest[net_NetGraph, n_Integer] /; n >= 1 :=
 NetGraph[
  ConstantArray[net, n]
  , Flatten@FoldPairList[{
      Thread[Rule @@ Outer[NetPort, {##}, Information[net, "InputPortNames"]]]
      , #2} &, Range@n]
  ]
```

```
NetGraph[
  {CatenateLayer[0], LinearLayer[2], PartLayer[1], PartLayer[2]}
  , {NetPort/@{"a","b"}->1->2->{3,4}, Thread[{3,4}->NetPort/@{"a","b"}]}//Flatten
  , "a"->"Real", "b"->"Real"
  ];
  
mutiportNest[%, 3]
```